# PhantomJS server running in Docker container

Tags: docker, phantomjs

I need to run PhantomJS server to generate images on demand. When I set this up on a standard Amazon Linux EC2 instance, it works fine.

However, I want to distribute it in a Docker container. Using the Amazon Linux base (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/amazon_linux_container_image.html) I include the following RPMS:

```
RUN \
  yum update && \
  yum install -y tar \
  yum install -y bzip2 \
  yum install -y freetype6 \
  yum install -y fontconfig \
  yum install -y freetype-devel \
  yum install -y fontconfig-devel \
  yum install -y libicu-devel \
  yum install -y libpng-devel \
  yum install -y libjpeg-devel \
  yum install -y gperf \
  yum install -y bison \
  yum install -y flex \
  yum install -y gcc \
  yum install -y gcc-c++
```

And then set up the phantomjs server as I did on the standard EC2 instance.

When launched, this generates images, but the images are missing their text labels. I can't find any debug output, and I didn't write the original code to generate the image.

Could anyone suggest what might be missing from the Docker container? I didn't have to install any extra libraries in the EC2 instance to get it to work. I've also tried increasing the spec of the host instance image in case there were issues with RAM.

Sample broken image:

https://gm1.ggpht.com/RxVy2Q6KpRVRxSPCoVEupfnl2ieHY9dr9Vu8o9P4JOjw4FqVsEfPgW1leA59R8n2hNF9u6cmL3LLO3idArCWBiE1EFpIz5CI9n29z1_95sC0lesTy6oxkcIoBoHMFNdMNSqURW9Sc1Is8Sd1t-YWsQKgJvtUsotBmRaEOWSKr7JpyjY6stSl1xJiJ5enc7ccvKTkPcuFNMl_NQCrv9b44brzpFjO2y6ZDrfBZolFXc-hqXvbRFazsRd-IVFh4mENLxVmQpeqbRug-egBHV_LCmj0ohBToxT4_b6_pqZpim9MZR6KFCX7QDu-rGtlhpMeweeDZ8uRkPwYyZ48hiEAQpVPAfsHNQGHR_kcRSN7-3bKDZJKjvPtcQjn-5bR-AMwX5B8iqFGyLLaG4QeA7AykmPJ4LGrX8aboPRRSdkH9EdYwEa4wH4IogHa6m4-OobG1FLdEgnveHzVL4XkB3zesrKa3-t5TgdL8nP9xTLaId2uLdqVO39QPTxKGrutyFJst1WhsdoUiBYhLD4JQZW0COBaQB9Kdu-anLpgaZ4oObrtqfzVRxrjdL5s7Qf_FagPtyZiSra2RfF3uDEpjRi0w3BSd8P-PvC2jmTqvuMz4rK-Go9pLLU1Dsqz3mR7p70yE7SVTzVy61YJLYT_NW3vAgHIir_HuJ4fpA3vg8qc2WGgUbOB83QtBsxQoIvu0oyIqq7k7pYzJ6SKCA=s0-l75-ft-l75-ft

Answer (score 1):

I eventually resolved this by using an Ubuntu base rather than an Amazon Linux base. Never determined what was missing from Amazon Linux.